# jQuery is not defined on my staging server but works fine on my local

Tags: jquery

If you pop open [this page](http://dev.betterhumanrace.com/) with your javascript console, you'll notice a bunch of JS errors. I don't get these errors in my local environment and it seems like it is happening because $ is not defined.  I have tried to mimic my local environment exactly on staging by using the same environment.rb file and removing all JS caching but it is making no difference.  Can anyone tell why jQuery is crapping out?  It might be something really stupid, but I need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: really? odd. what is your environment?  are you sure you are looking at a JS console?

Comment: Perhaps it's as simple as you've got NoScript and don't have it enabled for the staging server? Just a long shot...

Comment: I'm on windows vista + firefox 3.6 .. and I can see something you're logging in the firebug console like "_toolbarInstalled = false", but everything seems to work ok

Comment: The upvotes on @Matias's comments suggests that it works for 3 other people. I'm one of them, @Code Duck is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reuploading it. From a freshly download copy from the jQuery site if you have to. It may be an encoding error or something like that.

It breaks for me.

Comment: I tried loading it from google ajax libraries and it makes no difference.

Comment: Try removing the other libraries one by one to see if another is conflicting or causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. I don't know why, because you need to move

```
    <script src="http://dev.betterhumanrace.com/javascripts/jquery.js?1276572679" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to be above

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
```

in the source. You can't use $ before you've loaded the script that defines it.

Comment: i thought i did that but i guess not.  i guess if it's not above it will work occasionally...but odd it worked EVERY time on my local machine

Comment: Logically, scripts are executed in order, and $ is not defined when that inline script runs, so it *should* throw an error. It did work for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load it from Google. I think it's a pretty good solution:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery

You can point to "latest" so it's always the latest version.

You will need an API key, which will be free. :)

Good luck,

Flavio

Comment: look at the source, i am doing that

Comment: You don't need an api key to load jQuery from google's CDN. Just put a     `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` tag in.

Comment: if you want to use the latest you will need it. Just read the site...
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#Introduction

Warning: You need your own API key. In the example below, replace "INSERT-YOUR-KEY" with your own, unique key. Without your own key, these examples won't work. 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY"></script>Next, you load the libraries is by using google.load() to name a library and your prefered version. E.g.: 

  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");

Comment: yes, you are correct on that, but you don't really need all that to load from google CDN... just `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` will do... see it here, http://jsbin.com/

Comment: That is only if you want to use google.load.  As they say, "Each library is available via both google.load() and directly, via <script/> tag". If you want the latest, in a normal script tag as I posted, you just specify the version as 1 or 1.4 rather than specifically as 1.4.2.